# Automate Azure log retrieval

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have azure portal. I do manual steps each time.

Getting event logs:

1. Click on Cloud Services
2. Click on “abc123”
3. Click on “CONFIGURE”
4. Click on Remote in the bottom status bar
5. In the Role Drop Down select “”
6. Check the enable desktop for this role
7. Give an user name “abc”
8. Give a password, confirm the password, and save it in MPL
9. Select create a new certificate
10. Give a random expiry date of 6 months validity.
11. Press the tick button in the bottom right hand side.
12. Once this is done, click on “INSTANCES”
13. Click on 123abc

Instead of doing manually each time, can I get a script to login to the site and instance and get the required logs?

Comment: What kind of logs are you talking about? The steps you describe above are for enabling Remote Desktop in your Cloud Service.

Comment: Without enabling remote desktop on cloud services. Can i get logs using script. Logs can be c:\windows\eventlogs or c:\logs (such kind of thngs).

Comment: Yes. You can do that. I suggest you read up on Azure Diagnostics. HTH.